# Unicode for nine tenths?

Tags: html, unicode

after a fair bit of Googling, I can't seem to find the unicode representation for the nine tenths fraction. Any idea what it is?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_numerals#Fractions

Comment: It most certainly does exist. ⁹⁄₁₀.

Comment: That's not the vulgar fraction. You have four characters there. Many fractions have single character versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: `&#x2079;&#x2044;&#x2081;&#x2080;`

Produces: ⁹⁄₁₀

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a couple of things to get nine tenths and keep it readable.

Firstly there's the magical `&frasl;` html entity.

We can combine this with `sub` and `sup` to indicate our above/below numbers in our fraction.

Together this turns out to:

```
<sup>9</sup>&frasl;<sub>10</sub>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CL8Js/ OR <sup>9</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub>

Comment: You don't really need a separate demo when you could put it right into your answer, you know...

Comment: +1 @Jamie edited for you. If you don't like it, feel free to revert.

Comment: This works, but it's not a unicode representation as was asked for... ;)

Comment: @awm But the question contained the tag `html`!